# Should I first get a visitor visa to study Chinese or apply directly for resident visa?

Tags: visa, canada, taiwan

I want to go to Taiwan soon to study Chinese for more than 6 months, and I found out I can either apply for a resident visa from Canada or first get a visitor visa (renewable to a total of 6 months) that I can then convert to a resident visa in Taiwan. I think it comes out cheaper in the end to go directly with the resident visa. In this last case, however, a health certificate is required and many people told me it's much easier to get this done in Taiwan.

Did anyone apply for the resident visa directly, and would you suggest doing that? Is it as easy to get as the visitor visa, given that you provide all the required documents?